# MongoDB & Meteor - Query to push into nested array does not work, no error thrown

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, database

I am attempting to push data into a nested array inside of a Mongo collection. I've followed along the Mongo documentation here, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/, but have not had any luck pushing into the array. No errors or exceptions are thrown and the syntax *looks* right...

In this example, I'm attempting to update the `buyer.boards` titled *'Board One'* by pushing a new string into it's `idArr` array.  Is there something wrong with my query?

**Mongo Collection**

```
// User Document from Meteor.users Collection:
{
    _id: 'userIdqwerty',
    buyer: {
        boards: [
            {
                title: 'Board One',
                idArr: ['id123', 'id456', 'id678']
            },
            {
                title: 'Board Two',
                idArr: ['idABC']
            },
            {
                title: 'Board Three',
                idArr: ['id12345678', 'idqwertyuu']
            },
        ]
    };
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var options = {
    boardTitle: 'Board One',
    newId: 'idZjodFsp',
    userId: 'userIdqwerty'
};

Meteor.users.update(
    { 
        _id:options.userId, 
        'buyer.boards.$.title':options.boardTitle 
    },
    { $push: { 
        'buyer.boards.$.idArr':options.newId }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the positional operator(`$`) from the `query` parameter of the `update` function.

```
Meteor.users.update(
    { 
        _id:options.userId, 
        'buyer.boards.title':options.boardTitle 
    },
    { $push: { 
        'buyer.boards.$.idArr':options.newId }
    }
);
```

From the docs:

```
db.collection.update(
   { <array>: value ... },
   { <update operator>: { "<array>.$" : value } }
)
```

The positional operator should be used in the `update` parameter and **not** in the `query` parameter. This updates only the first `boards` object that has the matching `title`.