# Mongo Db insert element into nested mongo array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have following document structure

```
{
   assets : {
              type : [
                       {
                        type : spread
                        scene : [
                                    {
                                      ....
                                    },
                                    {
                                      ....
                                    }

                                ] 
                       }
                     ]      
            }

}
```

So I want to add new element in "scene" array with match condition of type "spread" in same document

How can I write Mongo Update query for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Following is example array

```
{
   assets : {
              type : [
                       {
                        type : spread
                        scene : [
                                    {
                                      ....
                                    },
                                    {
                                      ....
                                    }

                                ] 
                       }
                     ]      
            }

}
```

Reference link
[MongoDB & Meteor - Query to push into nested array does not work, no error thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804441/mongodb-meteor-query-to-push-into-nested-array-does-not-work-no-error-throw)

And query which insert new element in scene array is

```
db.PhotostoryDesigner.update(
    { 
        "photostoryId":"123", 
        "assets.type.type":"spreads" 
    },
    {"$push": { 
        'assets.type.$.scene':{"$each":[
            {
              "scene_id": "1",
              "name": "Ad hoc 1",
              "spread": [
                {
                  "spreadId": "7725",
                  "name": "PAGE 1-2",
                  "asset": []
                }
              ]
            }
        ]}}
    }
);
```